# Not registering day as invalid in non leap year

Tags: java

I am working on a program which takes in 3 ints for month day and year, and outputs the date. Im having trouble with the day part and the whole leap year thing. Here is my code:

```
public void setDay(int d) {
  int m = getMonth();
  int y = getYear();
  while (m > 0 && m <= 12) {
     if ((m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 ||
     m == 8 || m == 10 || m == 12) && (d > 0 && d <= 31)) {
        day = d;
        break;
     }
     else if ((m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11) && (d > 0 && d <= 30)) {
        day = d;
        break;
     }
     else if (m == 2) {
        if ((y % 400 == 0) || ((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0))) {
           if (d <= 29) {
              day = d;
           }
           else {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day");
           }

        }
        else {
           if (day <= 28) {
              day = d;
           }
           else {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day");
           }
        }

        break;
     }
     else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day");
     }


  }
```

}

Everything works fine, except when i the date is, 2, 29, 2001 for example, its supposed to throw the exception, but it does not it just prints it out normally

Comment: What's wrong with `java.util.Calendar`? You probably can use a debugger and figure out the problem in your code, don't you think? What are the actual values of `d`, `m` and `y` when you reach the `while`

Comment: You're also missing the edge case where `d < 1` in February. That's the sort of thing where you should state that condition once at the top and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (with a clearer message, such as "day of month (%d) cannot be less than 1") instead of repeating the check everywhere.

Comment: @RC. those values are predetermined via other methods, in this case the input is: month - 2, day - 29, year 2001

Answer (score 2):

You have problem here:

```
if (day <= 28) {
              day = d;
           }
```

should be:

```
if (d <= 28) {
              day = d;
           }
```

Comment: I've fixed this but my problem still persists

Comment: Change this: int m = getMonth(); int y = getYear(); to: int m = 2; int y = 2001;
if it will be working correctly, then you have issues with getMonth(), getYear() (maybe getMonth() is giving 0 for January, 1 for Feberuary?)